# Showing data on List View from Firebase - IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get information from Firebase and Showing it on ListView using Information Class. In CustomList it is showing this error

> Process: com.legiontechsolutions.antigravity, PID: 21862
>       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter {
    private static Activity context;
    private static ArrayList<Information> arrayList;
    TextView name, amount, date;


    public CustomList(@NonNull Activity context, ArrayList<Information> arrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item);
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.e(".............", "" + getItem(position));
        Information information = (Information) getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }


        name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.creadits);

        name.setText(information.name);
        amount.setText(" " + information.email);
        date.setText(information.mobile + "  ");
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here i am setting this adapter

```
try {
                    adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), arrayList);
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    Log.e("Exception is:", "" + e);
                }
                listViewCustomers.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ArrayAdapter like this. Default Array Adapter and R.layout.simple_list_item_1 show one property on the ListView. If you want to show more than one property on the ListView you should use Custom Array Adapter.

R.layout.simple_list_item_1 has one TextView, but your Information model has 5 property. If you use with your Information list on default adapter, it shows in ListView information.toString().

Please check link on below:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: thanls for your help. now i am getting a new error. 

Information information = (Information) getItem(position);

it is getting me null

Comment: Where do you use this code? on item click or getView ?

Comment: i want it in "getView"

Comment: You should pass the arrayList to the super method. super(context, R.layout.list_item, arrayList);

Comment: If you pass the arrayList to super, adapter hold the reference of arraylist and getItem works.